# How to toggle auto-add-pages in wp-cli for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I've got a menu in Wordpress and I want to toggle the checkbox "auto-add-pages" via wp-cli.

Tried sth. like `wp option update auto-add-pages 1` but that doesn't work. I guess because it doesn't know for which menu it should be.

Anybody out there to help me out?
thx in advance